# Fibrations with non-simply connected base and rational homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $p\colon E\to B$ be a fibration with fibres simply connected and homotopy equivalent to a compact CW-complex.
Must $p_*\colon H_3(E;\mathbb{Q})\to H_3(B;\mathbb{Q})$ be surjective?

COMMENTS.
Yes if (EDIT) $B$ is simply connected, even if the fibre is not compact but just finite-dimensional.
In general, finite-dimensionality is not enough: consider the homotopy fibre sequence $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\mathbb{Z}^3\to T^3\setminus\mathrm{point}\to T^3$.

MOTIVATION.
If $p_*\colon H_3(E;\mathbb{Q})\to H_3(B;\mathbb{Q})$ is surjective, then any bundle gerbe over $p\colon E\to B$ is rationally trivial,
cf. M. Murray, D. Stevenson, A note on bundle gerbes and infinite-dimensionality (http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4922).

Comment: What exactly do you mean for "fibration"? A locally trivial bundle? A Serre fibration?

Comment: I mean Serre fibration. For locally trivial bundles, the question is equally interesting for me.


Comment: For locally trivial bundles, it is also natural to ask the fibre to be homeomorphic (not just homotopy equivalent) to a compact CW-complex.


Comment: @Semen: I tried to prove your claim in the special case when $\pi_1(B) $acts trivially. Are you implicitly using a fact from rational homotopy theory? Namely, the result that appears here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81139/homology-of-loop-space ?

Comment:  @John: I found a mistake in my proof for trivial $\pi_1$-action
 (I used only the Serre spectral sequence, no rational homotopy theory).
 If $B$ is simply connected, the claim follows from Theorem 2 in
 Gotay-Lashof-Sniatycki-Weinstein
 "Closed forms on symplectic fibre bundles"
 (http://www.pims.math.ca/~gotay/GLSW.pdf).


Comment:  If the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on the fibre (not just on the homology) is trivial,
 we can make $B$ simply connected by attaching 2-cells
 and extend the fibration over the new $B$.
 $H_3(B)$ will not change.
 Since the fibre is simply connected,
 no new 3-homology classes will appear in $E$.
 QED


Comment: I was able to construct a proof when $B$ simply connected by pulling back the fibration along the 3-skeleton of $B$. This allows us to assume $B$ has dimension 3 and also is a suspension $\Sigma Z$, where $Z$ is connected. 

Comment: Here's how it goes, I think: If $H_3(E;\Bbb Q)\to H_3(B;\Bbb Q)$ failed to be onto, then it's not hard to show that there's a class $x\in H^2(F;\Bbb Q)$ which maps non-trivially under the homomorphism $H^2(F;\Bbb Q)\to H^2(\Omega B;\Bbb Q)$ and whose image comes from an element of $H^3(B;\Bbb Q) =H2(Z;\Bbb Q)$ with respect to the transgression $H^3(B;\Bbb Q) \to H^3(\Sigma \Omega B;\Bbb Q)$.This implies that $x^n$ is non−trivial for all $n$ (a contradiction),since $H^\ast(\Omega B;\Bbb Q)$ is a graded tensor algebra on $H^\ast(Z;\Bbb Q)$. 

Comment: I just looked at the Lashof-Sniatycki-Weinstein paper: their proof is similar to mine.

Comment: @Semen: "If the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on the fibre (not just on the homology) is trivial..." I'm not sure what you mean by that. There's a homomorphism of monoids $\pi_1(B) \to \pi_0(G(F))$, where the target is  the homotopy classes of self-equivalences of $F$. Do you want this  homomorphism to be trivial?

Comment: @John: Yes, exactly.


Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering the extent to which the assumptions can be tweaked. Let's assume 
$B$ is connected and with basepoint. Let $F$ be the fiber over the basepoint.

However, I *won't* assume $F$ is homotopy finite (i.e., homotopy equivalent to a finite complex). Nor will I assume anything about the action of $\pi_1(B)$. Rather, I will
assume

- $F$ is $1$-connected (just as Semen does), and
- $H_2(F;\Bbb Q)$ is trivial.

**Assertion:** 
With respect to these assumptions, $H_3(E;\Bbb Q) \to H_3(B;\Bbb Q)$ is surjective.

*Proof:*
By slight abuse of notation, let $E/F$ be the the mapping cone of the inclusion $F\to E$.

Then the Blakers-Massey theorem shows that
$E/F \to B$ is 3-connected.

We infer that $E\to B$ is $H_3({-};\Bbb Q)$-surjective if $E \to E/F$ is.

But the long exact homology sequence of $F \to E \to E/F$ and the assumption that $H_2(F;\Bbb Q)$ is trivial implies $H_3(E;\Bbb Q) \to H_3(E/F;\Bbb Q)$ is surjective.
$\square$

The above leads to the following question:  Is there a relationship between the hypotheses

(1) $F$ is homotopy finite, simply connected and $\pi_1(B)$ acts trivially on $H_*(F;\Bbb Q)$;

(2) $F$ is simply connected and $H_2(F;\Bbb Q)$ is trivial

?

Comment: Your result seems to be clear if you look at the Serre-Leray spectral sequence of the fibration.

Comment: Even with a non-trivial $\pi_1$-action?  In any case, I tend to be a luddite in these matters: I don't use spectral sequences when I can see the result without using them.

Comment: (I'm not surprised though: since the Blakers-Massey theorem is pretty closely related to the Serre exact sequence of the fibration.)

Comment: The spectral sequence gives something better: namely, the requested surjectivity holds if and only if the map from the coinvariants in `$H_2(F,\mathbb Q)$` to `$H_2(E, \mathbb Q)$` is injective.

Comment: Angelo: your observation ("something better") can be also seen without the spectral sequence. It uses the observation that there is a fiber sequence ΣF∧ΩB→E/F→B such that the composite ΣF∧ΩB→E/F→ΣF is the Hopf construction of the action of ΩB on F. I had decided not to post this in my original answer, because I wanted to keep things simple.

Comment: The assumption $H_2(F;\mathbb{Q})=0$ is too restrictive.
